# Is there a configuration where you can tell NPM to downgrade if package version isn't available?

Tags: npm, npm-install

If a package version, or peer dependency version is unavailable during an `npm install`, is it possible to configure NPM to ignore the version, and downgrade to the next lower version automatically (perhaps with a warning)?

```
No matching version found for @babel/generator@^7.18.9. 

In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting 
a package version that doesn't exist.
```

However, it exists [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/generator/v/7.18.9). While this is a issue probably for babel, we run a private npm-read-group that updates only every few hours, and it can be an issue when downloading packages that have just been updated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know you should define "latest" as value. For example:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "latest"
  }
}
```

I do not recommend doing this, but it should work for what you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, this doesn't solve the issue, I need to downgrade if the npm package or one of it's peer dependencies aren't found.

Comment: Got it. Making my research.